# Can anyone please help me with generating new images using GAN?

Tags: google-colaboratory, generative-adversarial-network, image-augmentation

I've been trying to generate (255x255) images using GAN, although I am able to train and generate 28x28 MNIST images, but I'm not able to generate custom images. I tried changing a lot of parameters in generator and discriminator networks, but I'm not able to generate even a single image. All I can see is a blank or dark image. Please help me with a proper solution as I'm approaching my semester deadline.

[the output which im getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Fr4l.png)

[output which im expecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mldnp.jpg)

Comment: Hi @Codexsys-7! Could you provide some more details? E.g. share your code, which hyperparameters are you using for your models and training and your plotting function?

Comment: sorry, but the issue is resolved, I have tried using styelgan3 and it worked. Thanks for your reply.